# Having difficulty dropping multiple columns from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a newly created Pandas dataframe, which for some reason I can't drop the columns from.

RangeIndex: 2617 entries, 0 to 2616
Columns: 111 entries, access to zoning
dtypes: object(111)
memory usage: 2.2+ MB
None

`print list(df)`

['access', 'age', 'attic', 'basement_type', 'bathrooms', 'bedrooms_total', 'buyer', 'buyer_city', 'buyer_country', 'buyer_postal_code', 'colisting_agent_id', 'construction', 'csa_number', 'date_expired_hidden', 'date_listed', 'date_sold', 'date_unconditional', 'distance_to_schools', 'distance_to_transportation', 'district', 'ensuites', 'exterior_features', 'exterior_finish', 'fireplace_types', 'fireplaces', 'flooring', 'fuel', 'heating', 'id', 'interior_features', 'internet_remarks']

````
df = df.drop(['buyer', 'buyer_city', 'buyer_country', 'colisting_agent_id'], axis=1, inplace=True)


print list(df)```



TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-1db0e7488634> in <module>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 print list(df)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inplace=True` argument will drop at the source i.e. the dataframe itself and returns `None`.

So, when you use `inplace=True` then don't assign it back to `df`

Here the error is because the df variable is assigned to `None` and calling a `list` constructor on `None` will raise an error.

```
>>> df.drop(list_of_cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: makes total sense! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Either you should do:

```
df = df.drop(['buyer', 'buyer_city', 'buyer_country'], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df.drop(['buyer', 'buyer_city', 'buyer_country'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```